# Function that check and implement regular expression to data if regular expression rang{a,b} no bigger then min,max

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

write a function that will take on a value from input, for example, and a value from another input where the user enters a regularity. And it will look whether there is such a construction {a, b} in the regular season
search in a certain range, here is something that may be new Regexp (‘\ w {2,3}’)
and if so, for example a should be no more than 1 (min) and b should be no more than 7 (max). And then apply this regex to the data value

Comment: Can you show us what you've done already so we can explain why it didn't work ... please edit and use ctrl-k around your highlighted code for indentation.

Comment: write a regular season to check if there is such a construction in the line "{a, b}" and if it does, check that a is not less than 1 and b not more than 3 for example, instead of 1 and 3 they can

Answer (score 0):

Regex is there to match a string and ev. "parse" out specific parts. Usually it's not used to do some other comparison. This does not mean you can't match up a range of integers, but it's matching, not comparing.

So I can check if a value "123" or "120" is greater or equal to 120, by using regex: 12\d+

The regex says it must start with 12 and have at least one additional digit, so this satisfies the has to be greater or equal to 120.

For greater than 120 I'd use: (12[1-9] | 13\d+).

Great example is valid US date (MM/dd/yyyy):
^(0[1-9]|1[012])/-[/-]\d{4}$

Comment: write a regular season to check if there is such a construction in the line "{a, b}" and if it does, check that a is not less than 1 and b not more than 3 for example, instead of 1 and 3 they can

Comment: hi @Иван, i provided a way to solve your problem, but solving it, well, that remains on you. I can tell that with regex you can't do that with variable min-max values (actually you might do that, but it would be probably not worth doing that way). also note that even HTML has a min/max attribute which is exactly suited for such situations. with console/win-forms it's even more easier.